# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter

Tags: java, ssl, https, tls1.2, okhttp

I'm using `OKHttp 4.0.0` (java 11, Mac Mojave) and getting `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter`. The code and log are below:

Code

```
KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
clientStore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/me/Downloads/certs/my-cert.pfx")), "my-password".toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(clientStore, "my-password".toCharArray());
KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
trustStore.load(null, "changeit".toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init((KeyStore)null);
TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();

final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(kms,tms,new SecureRandom());

//thin wrapper around Okhttp client
String res = TLSHttpClientBuilder.aHttpsClient();
//this calls sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager) on the builder 
.withSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0])
    .withDebugModeEnabled()
    .build(new MetricRegistry())
    .post("https://staging.xxx", Map.of(), PAYLOAD, String.class);
```

Partial log output showing OkHttp events and exception. It looks to be failing late in the process after the `responseHeadersStart` event fires.

```
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:44 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: --> END POST (678-byte body)
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:44 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [54 ms] dnsStart: staging.ws-cert.idms.lexisnexis.com
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:44 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [195 ms] dnsEnd: [staging.xxxx]
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:44 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [204 ms] connectStart: staging.xxxx DIRECT
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:44 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [262 ms] secureConnectStart
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:45 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [574 ms] secureConnectEnd: Handshake{tlsVersion=TLS_1_2 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 peerCertificates=[CN=xxx, O=xxx, L=xxx, ST=xx, C=xx, SERIALNUMBER=xxx, OID.xxxx=xxxx, xxx=US, xxx=xxx, CN=Thawte EV RSA CA 2018, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US, CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US] localCertificates=[CN=xxxx]}
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:45 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [574 ms] connectEnd: http/1.1
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:45 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [576 ms] connectionAcquired: Connection{staging.xxx:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=staging.xxxx:443 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 protocol=http/1.1}
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:45 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [578 ms] requestHeadersStart
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:45 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [579 ms] requestHeadersEnd
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:45 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [579 ms] requestBodyStart
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:45 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [581 ms] requestBodyEnd: byteCount=678
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:45 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [582 ms] responseHeadersStart
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:45 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [683 ms] responseFailed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:45 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:45 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [685 ms] connectionReleased
Jul 22, 2019 12:41:45 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [685 ms] callFailed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter
```

**Update**

Running with `-Djava.net.debug=ssl:handshake`

```
Jul 22, 2019 8:35:42 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [121 ms] secureConnectStart
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.755 EDT|SignatureScheme.java:282|Signature algorithm, ed25519, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.756 EDT|SignatureScheme.java:282|Signature algorithm, ed448, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.760 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:256|Ignore, context unavailable extension: cookie
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.764 EDT|PreSharedKeyExtension.java:624|No session to resume.
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.764 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:256|Ignore, context unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.764 EDT|ClientHello.java:651|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "94 C0 48 D0 25 B0 73 86 7F 90 15 5F 59 4B 76 30 8A A7 5C 46 08 D5 F0 28 27 59 EF 89 8A 10 91 38",
  "session id"          : "B7 99 79 9F 26 AF B4 BD FC 57 5D F4 5B 00 65 55 E9 6D D7 9B C3 26 FF 6F 6E 6A FD 5C 5F 63 32 F9",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [

  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.865 EDT|ServerHello.java:866|Consuming ServerHello handshake message (
"ServerHello": {
  "server version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "68 41 E1 8E 09 CF EA BD EA 93 D3 4B 85 A0 4C 72 D0 16 EC 71 C9 F0 34 9A 97 1E 9D 57 73 B8 37 F2",
  "session id"          : "4C AC BB F5 B3 22 6C 2B B0 2A D5 54 3F 63 90 43 70 F7 95 A3 90 91 B7 6C 2F 6A A3 08 8A D9 66 AF",
  "cipher suite"        : "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030)",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    },
    "server_name (0)": {
      <empty extension_data field>
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.866 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:169|Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.866 EDT|ServerHello.java:962|Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.866 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:188|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.866 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:188|Consumed extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.867 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:169|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.867 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:169|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.867 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:188|Consumed extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.867 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:169|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.867 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:159|Ignore unsupported extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.868 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:159|Ignore unsupported extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.868 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:188|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.868 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:159|Ignore unsupported extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.868 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:211|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.868 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:203|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.868 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:203|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.868 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:211|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.869 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:203|Ignore unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.869 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:203|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.869 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:203|Ignore unavailable extension: extended_master_secret
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.869 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:203|Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.869 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:203|Ignore unavailable extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.869 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:211|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.869 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:203|Ignore unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.876 EDT|CertificateMessage.java:358|Consuming server Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "03 31 01 5A E5 A7 53 ED F2 78 1A A4 9A 75 EE A8",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=Thawte EV RSA CA 2018, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US",
    "not before"         : "2019-02-25 19:00:00.000 EST",
    "not  after"         : "2020-02-26 07:00:00.000 EST",
    "subject"            : "CN=xxx, O=xxx., L=Boca Raton, ST=Florida, C=US, SERIALNUMBER=xxx=Minnesota, xxxx=US, OID.2.5.4.15=xxx",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2 Criticality=false
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
        AuthorityInfoAccess [
          [
           accessMethod: ocsp
           accessLocation: URIName: http://status.thawte.com
        , 
           accessMethod: caIssuers
           accessLocation: URIName: http://cacerts.thawte.com/ThawteEVRSACA2018.crt
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: E7 01 FC 0C 16 18 CA 7D   B2 8C EC 87 27 A3 6F 61  ............'.oa
        0010: 81 3B 84 39                                        .;.9
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:false
          PathLen: undefined
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
        CRLDistributionPoints [
          [DistributionPoint:
             [URIName: http://cdp.thawte.com/ThawteEVRSACA2018.crl]
        ]]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
        CertificatePolicies [
          [CertificatePolicyId: [2.16.840.1.114412.2.1]
        [PolicyQualifierInfo: [
          qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
          qualifier: 0000: 16 1C 68 74 74 70 73 3A   2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 64 69  ..https://www.di
        0010: 67 69 63 65 72 74 2E 63   6F 6D 2F 43 50 53        gicert.com/CPS

        ]]  ]
          [CertificatePolicyId: [2.23.140.1.1]
        []  ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
        ExtendedKeyUsages [
          serverAuth
          clientAuth
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_Encipherment
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
        SubjectAlternativeName [
          DNSName: xxx.com
          DNSName: xxx.com
          DNSName: xxxx.com
          DNSName: staging.xxxx.com
          DNSName: staging.xxxx.com
          DNSName: staging.xxxx.com
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 51 55 3F FF 74 58 F3 1F   55 03 38 58 07 B6 17 13  QU?.tX..U.8X....
        0010: 1B A3 B5 E7                                        ....
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]},
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "06 96 8F 96 4A E8 23 56 C7 4E 17 C2 B5 36 5B 00",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US",
    "not before"         : "2017-11-06 07:22:57.000 EST",
    "not  after"         : "2027-11-06 08:22:57.000 EDT",
    "subject"            : "CN=Thawte EV RSA CA 2018, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
        AuthorityInfoAccess [
          [
           accessMethod: ocsp
           accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.digicert.com
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: B1 3E C3 69 03 F8 BF 47   01 D4 98 26 1A 08 02 EF  .>.i...G...&....
        0010: 63 64 2B C3                                        cd+.
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:0
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
        CRLDistributionPoints [
          [DistributionPoint:
             [URIName: http://crl3.digicert.com/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crl]
        ]]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
        CertificatePolicies [
          [CertificatePolicyId: [2.5.29.32.0]
        [PolicyQualifierInfo: [
          qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
          qualifier: 0000: 16 1C 68 74 74 70 73 3A   2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 64 69  ..https://www.di
        0010: 67 69 63 65 72 74 2E 63   6F 6D 2F 43 50 53        gicert.com/CPS

        ]]  ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
        ExtendedKeyUsages [
          serverAuth
          clientAuth
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: E7 01 FC 0C 16 18 CA 7D   B2 8C EC 87 27 A3 6F 61  ............'.oa
        0010: 81 3B 84 39                                        .;.9
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]},
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "02 AC 5C 26 6A 0B 40 9B 8F 0B 79 F2 AE 46 25 77",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA1withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US",
    "not before"         : "2006-11-09 19:00:00.000 EST",
    "not  after"         : "2031-11-09 19:00:00.000 EST",
    "subject"            : "CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: B1 3E C3 69 03 F8 BF 47   01 D4 98 26 1A 08 02 EF  .>.i...G...&....
        0010: 63 64 2B C3                                        cd+.
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:2147483647
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: B1 3E C3 69 03 F8 BF 47   01 D4 98 26 1A 08 02 EF  .>.i...G...&....
        0010: 63 64 2B C3                                        cd+.
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
]
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.906 EDT|ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:538|Consuming ECDH ServerKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ServerKeyExchange": {
  "parameters": {
    "named group": "secp256r1"
    "ecdh public": {
      0000: 04 31 BC 31 72 C2 55 60   9A D9 B9 E4 3E B5 2D DD  .1.1r.U`....>.-.
      0010: D3 26 BA 6C 89 3C 67 B4   AF D7 47 1E 2B 4A A8 A3  .&.l.<g...G.+J..
      0020: 20 BE AA 4B 14 4C C5 4C   05 E7 A3 A5 B3 D2 73 69   ..K.L.L......si
      0030: 2D 2D AF 83 68 05 D2 FB   D6 D2 45 A3 5E 09 14 81  --..h.....E.^...
      0040: A0                                                 .
    },
  },
  "digital signature":  {
    "signature algorithm": "rsa_pss_rsae_sha256"
    "signature": {
      0000: 8A 2A 47 7E 26 BC E8 57   83 9B 39 33 36 9A DE 9E  .*G.&..W..936...
      0010: A3 77 8D 57 DB 3E 11 8D   12 3C 39 71 B2 AF 2F B7  .w.W.>...<9q../.
      0020: 67 8F 5F C2 41 62 FC AA   CF 1A 47 6A 2F 62 7B C9  g._.Ab....Gj/b..
      0030: 52 7B 36 A9 3A 9E 49 8F   6C 2C 64 25 90 DA 49 01  R.6.:.I.l,d%..I.
      0040: 8E C7 44 5D 8D 4B 35 E3   BF 9C 3E 39 2B B1 07 E8  ..D].K5...>9+...
      0050: 30 10 D9 45 74 4F 0F F6   D4 91 B1 C2 E5 D6 CE 40  0..EtO.........@
      0060: 87 61 59 F4 02 19 FB 3D   0C 17 C0 64 52 97 BD B2  .aY....=...dR...
      0070: E6 37 6C C2 5F 87 18 C3   F3 47 8C 49 96 C7 18 B0  .7l._....G.I....
      0080: 1D F4 7C D3 18 40 57 67   1F A8 2B FB BA F4 6C CA  .....@Wg..+...l.
      0090: C7 76 DA 42 EC 4D E3 36   1B 80 54 E7 02 12 BB F4  .v.B.M.6..T.....
      00A0: BF C4 40 74 B5 9C FF E9   11 65 1D DE CE CA 7A 8C  ..@t.....e....z.
      00B0: 64 BA E8 EC 7D FA 4B 61   27 0C D3 F9 66 B0 EF 8E  d.....Ka'...f...
      00C0: 7D 22 9E 5E C0 4D 8D 97   0C 86 8C 66 C4 0F 2F 7A  .".^.M.....f../z
      00D0: D9 B8 DC 77 D6 3F 06 99   72 96 E7 90 87 A8 93 59  ...w.?..r......Y
      00E0: D6 C9 66 B4 1A F4 00 70   11 3F 7B 43 25 DF DF 5E  ..f....p.?.C%..^
      00F0: 36 01 63 EA E6 38 FC 92   44 47 28 65 A6 BC CD D0  6.c..8..DG(e....
    },
  }
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.907 EDT|CertificateRequest.java:651|Consuming CertificateRequest handshake message (
"CertificateRequest": {
  "certificate types": [rsa_sign, ecdsa_sign, dss_sign]
  "supported signature algorithms": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp512r1_sha512, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha256, dsa_sha384, dsa_sha512, dsa_sha1]
  "certificate authorities": [CN=thawte EV SSL CA - G3, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US, CN=VeridBetaCA, CN=Thawte EV RSA CA 2018, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US, CN=xxx, O=xxx, C=US, EMAILADDRESS=ca@trustwave.com, CN="Trustwave Organization Validation SHA256 CA, Level 1", O="Trustwave Holdings, Inc.", L=Chicago, ST=Illinois, C=US, CN=CAcert]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.908 EDT|ServerHelloDone.java:142|Consuming ServerHelloDone handshake message (
<empty>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.909 EDT|CertificateMessage.java:322|Produced client Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "00 AB 99 40 BB F9 7F 3E 8C 08 EE",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=xxx, O=xxx, C=US",
    "not before"         : "2019-07-16 09:28:47.000 EDT",
    "not  after"         : "2020-07-17 09:28:47.000 EDT",
    "subject"            : "CN=xxx",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: A7 3A 44 2D 62 9A 62 31   8A 7A 4F C6 5A 3E 6C 53  .:D-b.b1.zO.Z>lS
        0010: 9B 0D 3B 53                                        ..;S
        ]
        [CN=xxx, O=xxxx, C=US]
        SerialNumber: [    56940f10]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
        ExtendedKeyUsages [
          clientAuth
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 91 16 03 00 C1 40 CC 71   9F B4 49 31 3F 52 35 F8  .....@.q..I1?R5.
        0010: 26 BF DE 8A                                        &...
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
]
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.911 EDT|ECDHClientKeyExchange.java:401|Produced ECDHE ClientKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ClientKeyExchange": {
  "ecdh public": {
    0000: 04 C9 F0 6F C8 66 39 3D   65 EE DA E2 7D 2C C9 FE  ...o.f9=e....,..
    0010: 23 F9 DD 13 58 E7 3C 51   9E F8 96 59 33 93 C1 23  #...X.<Q...Y3..#
    0020: B6 4F 9D 04 6A 51 56 95   BA 66 3D F3 B6 3D DC 77  .O..jQV..f=..=.w
    0030: 2E 09 A9 62 E2 E8 67 FA   77 AA 98 FB 27 ED 79 A0  ...b..g.w...'.y.
    0040: 7A                                                 z
  },
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.938 EDT|CertificateVerify.java:743|Produced CertificateVerify handshake message (
"CertificateVerify": {
  "signature algorithm": rsa_pss_rsae_sha256
  "signature": {
    0000: 73 BC 50 D5 9B 82 E3 75   FA 04 63 C4 F5 34 29 6D  s.P....u..c..4)m
    0010: 54 68 5C 4C 33 24 94 B8   BA A3 91 1A DB AB 5C 4C  Th\L3$........\L
    0020: E7 54 EB 31 E2 17 83 0D   CF 1C EB CD 54 7F D6 89  .T.1........T...
    0030: F4 62 38 36 10 8E 04 E5   CE 9A DB 19 13 0F 42 20  .b86..........B 
    0040: 5C 67 95 EA 58 0A C6 9F   DB 6F CF AD 76 83 02 A3  \g..X....o..v...
    0050: 7F 37 B6 E1 11 6B 76 FD   AC 80 69 1C BB B6 23 9D  .7...kv...i...#.
    0060: 8E 04 DA 74 93 31 79 73   96 06 34 71 75 39 6D 41  ...t.1ys..4qu9mA
    0070: E4 F2 CA CF 94 46 84 8B   DE E4 48 6F 98 B5 5B 35  .....F....Ho..[5
    0080: 94 F2 68 38 6F 76 2B 4A   DF CA 49 41 93 3A 85 40  ..h8ov+J..IA.:.@
    0090: CA E7 48 02 19 B9 62 13   2A 01 95 D8 D4 A9 BF 3C  ..H...b.*......<
    00A0: 35 D2 B9 1D BE 99 80 61   66 EE 4C BC 6A CF 4F 38  5......af.L.j.O8
    00B0: FF 5F 63 0D F8 1E 59 06   80 70 69 81 6D 2E 38 8B  ._c...Y..pi.m.8.
    00C0: 9E E6 2B 38 50 BA A4 C5   28 5E 49 F1 F0 9F CD E5  ..+8P...(^I.....
    00D0: 48 E1 87 30 71 1F 03 DF   7C 43 BA 4A F1 F3 DD BF  H..0q....C.J....
    00E0: 1E 44 5F 90 65 3D BD 26   D2 DB 85 4A 95 D8 6D E3  .D_.e=.&...J..m.
    00F0: 8E C0 C3 BD D5 7A 72 6B   85 06 1E 21 0F B1 A5 BE  .....zrk...!....
  }
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.941 EDT|ChangeCipherSpec.java:109|Produced ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:42.942 EDT|Finished.java:395|Produced client Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: E6 A2 A8 D3 AC 4F 25 83   0D 69 FB 7C 
  }'}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:43.025 EDT|ChangeCipherSpec.java:143|Consuming ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:43.028 EDT|Finished.java:532|Consuming server Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: 90 41 AD 8D 99 B6 55 2A   39 1A 42 71 
  }'}
)
Jul 22, 2019 8:35:43 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [420 ms] secureConnectEnd: Handshake{tlsVersion=TLS_1_2 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 peerCertificates=[CN=xxxx.com, O=xxx., L=Boca Raton, ST=Florida, C=US, SERIALNUMBER=8M-543, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Minnesota, OID.1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US, OID.2.5.4.15=Private Organization, CN=Thawte EV RSA CA 2018, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US, CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US] localCertificates=[CN=xxx]}
Jul 22, 2019 8:35:43 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [420 ms] connectEnd: http/1.1
Jul 22, 2019 8:35:43 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [421 ms] connectionAcquired: Connection{xxxx:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=xxxx:443 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 protocol=http/1.1}
Jul 22, 2019 8:35:43 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [423 ms] requestHeadersStart
Jul 22, 2019 8:35:43 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [424 ms] requestHeadersEnd
Jul 22, 2019 8:35:43 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [424 ms] requestBodyStart
Jul 22, 2019 8:35:43 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [426 ms] requestBodyEnd: byteCount=678
Jul 22, 2019 8:35:43 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [427 ms] responseHeadersStart
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:43.078 EDT|HelloRequest.java:181|Consuming HelloRequest handshake message (
<empty>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:43.079 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:256|Ignore, context unavailable extension: cookie
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:43.081 EDT|PreSharedKeyExtension.java:624|No session to resume.
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:43.081 EDT|SSLExtensions.java:256|Ignore, context unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:43.081 EDT|ClientHello.java:651|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "41 7B EE A6 BA 5B 98 1B E1 B3 B1 2E 38 64 CA 74 70 18 C0 CC 2E 6F CD E4 DA DE E9 7B 28 02 19 7F",
  "session id"          : "A0 27 C5 87 F6 86 14 9B AA 35 67 F1 09 AF 56 CF 35 DF AB 26 27 DA AB D5 B5 E8 22 CC FC 4A DA 19",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [

  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:43.123 EDT|Alert.java:232|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "illegal_parameter"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:43.125 EDT|TransportContext.java:313|Fatal (ILLEGAL_PARAMETER): Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    ....

)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:43.125 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1361|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:43.125 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1380|close the SSL connection (initiative)
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2019-07-22 08:35:43.127 EDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1289|handling exception (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    ....

)
Jul 22, 2019 8:35:43 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [517 ms] responseFailed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter
Jul 22, 2019 8:35:43 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter
Jul 22, 2019 8:35:43 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [519 ms] connectionReleased
Jul 22, 2019 8:35:43 AM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: [519 ms] callFailed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: illegal_parameter
    at com.clearme.platform.http.HttpClient.execute(HttpClient.java:81)
    at com.clearme.platform.http.HttpClient.post(HttpClient.java:55)
    at com.clearme.platform.http.HttpClient.post(HttpClient.java:51)
    ....
```

Comment: You run your command using `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` java option and see if there is any more useful/obvious details in it. You can then update your post with the output

Comment: Already did that - will post